# Is there a way to recover missing or corrupt parts of a mov-file?

Tags: video, data-recovery, quicktime, screen-recording

I did a screen recording for 30 minutes, but the file only consists of 4 minutes. The thing is, the file is 935 MB, so I expect that the rest of the movie is in there, but something went wrong in the file recording. Could that be? Is there a way to investigate this? The purpose would be to recover the missing part of the recording?
I'm running macOS Catalina.

Comment: This actually sounds like the recording was **stopped** after four minutes, since ~1GB of video fits its length. I just tested with 2560x1440 resolution and 1min ~ 240MB. However, this very much depends on what screen resolution you are recording.

Comment: @X_841 I think you are right. I did a new screen recording while playing the old clip and it turned out the new clip was 1,37 GB. Thanks for your input!

Answer (score 2):

`ffmpeg` has `-err_detect ignore_err` which might find more of the video.

Install ffmpeg (install [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/) then `brew install ffmpeg`), then transcode the video:

```
ffmpeg -err_detect ignore_err -i path/to/input.mov -c copy path/to/output.mov
```